# jQuery - link working *only* after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, delayed-execution

I have a link:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Here's my link</a>
```

This is not a normal clickable link, it's coded in jQuery like this:

```
 $("#link").hover(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();   
    $("#tv").stop().animate({marginLeft: "50px"});
    $("#tv img)").animate({opacity: 1});
})
```

So after hovering unclickable link there's change of #tv's margin and opacity.

Is there any way of making this work only *after* the user hovers the link area with pointer for *more* than two seconds?

Because now everything happens in real time.

I know there's `delay()`, but it doesn't work because it just delays the animation and in this case I don't want *any* action if the pointer is over for less than two seconds.

Possible without a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var animateTimeout;

$("#link").hover(function() {
  if (animateTimeout != null) { 
    clearTimeout(animateTimeout); 
  }
  animateTimeout = setTimeout(animate, 2000);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(animateTimeout);
});

function animate() {
  //do animation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is called **[hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You just need [a `setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) to delay the code, along with [a `clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearTimeout) to clear it if the user leaves the link within 2 seconds.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mNWEq/2/

```
$("#link").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.data(this).timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#tv").stop().animate({marginLeft: "50px"});
        $("#tv img)").animate({opacity: 1});
    }, 2000);
}, function(e) {
    clearTimeout($.data(this,'timeout'));
});
```